# How to use the file Asserts in Nunit and check the files are present or not

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

how to use the file Asserts in Nunit and check the files are present or not.Need some examples for clear and basic understanding.Can any one please help me

Answer (score 13):

NUnit 3.0 includes a [FileOrDirectoryExistsConstraint](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/FileOrDirectoryExistsConstraint).

```
var filePath = "C:\pathtofile.txt";
Assert.That(filePath, Does.Exist);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use:

```
var fileName = @"C:\somedirectory\somefile.txt";

Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(fileName));
```

[FileAssert](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=fileAssert&r=2.6.3) can be only used for comparison of two actual files from disc of from some abstract stream

Comment: Hi,can you please give one example with code for checking the existence of a file.Actually my job is to access any folder and check whether the file is present or not in all folders or not.

Comment: Well. That is full example of code that tests if file exists. Only one line(without fileName declaration).. File.Exist() is a standard method that return True if file exists or False if not. And Assert.IsTrue method of NUnit check if File.Exists() returned True.

Comment: Hi,can you please tell me how to declare asserts and how to obtain the path.Please help its an entirely new job for me and i'm new to Nunit and coding

Answer (score 5):

[As of NUnit 2.9.7](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Pre-3.5-Release-Notes#nunit-297---august-8-2014)  (released just before this question was asked) you can use `FileAssert.Exists(@"C:\somedirectory\somefile.txt");`.

Answer (score 0):

The new Framework allows this also:

```
Ex. FileAssert.IsEqual(FileName1, FileName2);
    FileAssert.IsNotEqual(FileName1, FileName2);
```

To compare 2 Files.

Answer (score -1):

May be help you as below:
C#
You need to deploy your files on your UT project.

[DeploymentItem("file1.xml")]
Copies file1.xml from the build output directory to the deployment directory.
[DeploymentItem(@"Testfiles\")]
Copies all the files and folders in the Testfiles folder from the build output folder to the deployment folder. Subfolders are replicated in the deployment folder.
[DeploymentItem("file2.xml", "DataFiles")]
Creates a folder named DataFiles in the deployment folder, and copies file2.xml from the build output folder to DataFiles.

Assert.istrue(File.exist("your file"));

Comment: Hi,can you please tell me how to declare asserts and how to obtain the path.Please help its an entirely new job for me and i'm new to Nunit and coding